# Saved file1 into file2, how to rescue original file2?

Tags: macos

That is the question, accidentally saved empty file into a good file. It was an adobe illustrator project.

Is there any way to get it back?

I'm on Os X.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you could use a program like Recuva, which is free.
On Mac, the only alternative I know of that works decently well, and is still affordable, costs money, and that's [DiskWarrior](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFwQFjAA&url=http://www.alsoft.com/diskwarrior/&ei=z9C7T5muNeqI6AHjprz1Aw&usg=AFQjCNFAUCElg8bf10vV-Nqawmwu3otICQ&sig2=3jhwRCfkAD8hSC1JD_lcmg).

As far as I know (which, admittedly, about Mac's is not much beyond standard IT), there's no free alternatives, or built-in OS functions.

Comment: As noted by Dennis above, a time machine is the only reliable way to get your data back post-accident. You could help prevent data-loss in the future by using a versioning system, or an automated backup, but neither of those are 100% fool-proof. DiskWarrior and Recuva and other programs have a chance at getting your data back, but its not 100% guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a Time Machine backup?

Comment: If I had, it would be too easy =) I tried some recovering software, but i have 500GB hard drive, and there is no way to specify the folder to restore data. So I found it quicker to redraw that project, the more, it was not super difficult, and there were some snapshots.

Thank you for your response, anyway. I started thinking about time machine or something to backup, but now i have much more than half of space used on a hard drive.